# Upgrade locally installed modules for the new Perl version

Tags: cygwin, cpan, perl

I have several CPAN modules installed in `~/lib`. Apparently, `local::lib` is used, CPAN's default.

Now, I have upgraded my Perl version, and it stopped seeing those modules.

I understand that they probably need to be rebuilt from source, but all it takes is get their list this way or another and kick the CPAN install sequence going.

What is the standard way to do this? I'm sure there must an existing facility that addresses such a common need.

(already looked through `CPAN` and `local::lib` docs and the Net, of course)

UPDATE:

After looking at `~/lib`, I discovered that the modules have actually vanished from there. I don't know where they went. Comments show that "module vanishing" doesn't normally happen. So the question stands.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, local::lib has nothing to do with CPAN module/distro. Maybe you meant `cpan` installs to local::lib's dir by default, but that's not true. It only does so if it's been configured to do so.

Interestingly, the problem is normally that local::lib's directory is still seen by the upgraded Perl. local::lib uses `INSTALL_BASE`, which installs the modules in a way that the directory can only be used by that install of Perl. That's why I always strongly recommend *against* local::lib and `INSTALL_BASE`.

That fact that the directory is no longer visible is a good thing. You had to reinstall all the modules anyways, and this way, there won't be any mixups.

Comment: _"Maybe you meant cpan installs to local::lib's dir by default..."_ Exactly. When I configure CPAN, it offers a few choices how to install modules, and this is the default one.

Comment: 1) CPAN comes with Perl, so there's no need to install it. 2) CPAN doesn't know anything about install::lib. It most definitely doesn't default to using it. I would raise hell if did.

Comment: Well, I don't know where they went. All I know is that I installed e.g. `Term::ReadLine::Gnu` and `Log::Log4Perl` some time ago, and after upgrade, they weren't there. I could as well erase them myself accidentally (or maybe it's Cygwin).

Comment: So, you're saying that this doesn't normally happen, so my case is not a "common need" as I claimed it to be?

Comment: Re "Well, I don't know where they went", Like I've already said in my answer, you have to reinstall them anyway, so it doesn't matter where they went.

Comment: Re "so my case is not a 'common need' as I claimed it to be?", No idea what you mean. The only difference between you and someone else is that you didn't have to delete the existing modules yourself.

Comment: Whatever. Now, we are back where we started. If the modules aren't normally deleted by an upgrade, is there an already implemented solution to reinstall them automa_g_ically? Man, I expected to see a _built-in CPAN command_ for that!

Comment: I believe there is a way to get the list of installed modules. Not using `cpan`, though. I don't see why you need that. Just install the script you want to use, and the dependencies will be installed automatically

Comment: Re. local::lib, I think the OP is talking about [this](https://metacpan.org/pod/CPAN#pod5): "As of CPAN 1.9463, if you do not have permission to write the default perl library directories, CPAN's configuration process will ask you whether you want to bootstrap <local::lib>" If you choose to bootstrap, PERL_MB_OPT and PERL_MM_OPT are set in your .bashrc or equivalent; bootstrapping is the default option.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, That's unfortunate :(  [I had tested it, but I had permission to the lib dirs. I also grepped a file or two for any mention of install::lib, but apparently the wrong ones.]

Comment: @ikegami I got bitten by this when I tried mass-installing a module over SSH on a bunch of systems where cpan wasn't configured yet. Since there was no tty, the defaults got used.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, I use the defaults, but I also use perlbrew.